# After removing index.php from ci, code is not working properly

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I have created a simple login form in ci and with wamp. I removed index.php from URL by writing this code in .htaccess:-

```
             <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
              RewriteEngine On
              RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
              RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
              RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
              RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
              RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
              </IfModule>
```

I have also enabled rewrite_module in apache.
From URL, index.php was successfully removed and view(login page) was also loaded in the browser. But when I am clicking on the submit button, it is not redirecting to another page, nither to view nor to the controller.

View code: -

```
       <form method = "post" action = "<?php echo site_url(); ?>Home/xyz">
            <div class = "row" align ="center">
                <?php if($error=$this->session->flashdata('Login_failed')) { ?>

                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <?php echo $error; ?>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php if($error=$this->session->flashdata('already_existing')) { ?>

                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <?php echo $error; ?>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php if($error=$this->session->flashdata('logged_out')) { ?>

                <div class="alert alert-info">
                    <?php echo $error; ?>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
            <div class="col-md-3">
            <label for = "emailid"><em>EMAIL_ID</em></label>
            <input type = "email" name = "eid"  class = "form-control" placeholder = "Enter Email id" value = "<?php if(($this->input->post('submit'))&&($this->input->post('eid'))){echo $this->input->post('eid'); } ?>" required = "required"><br>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
            <label for = "password"><em>Password</em></label>
            <input type = "password" name = "pass" class = "form-control" placeholder = "Enter password" required="required"><br>
            </div>
             <div class = "col-md-3">
            <label for = "password"></label>
            <input type="submit" class = "btn btn-primary" name = "submit" value = "Sign_in"><br>
        </div>
          </div>



</form>
```

Controller Code: -

```
       class Home extends CI_Controller{

 function __construct() {
parent::__construct();
$this->load->model('Test');
$this->load->library('session');
  }

public function index(){
    $this->load->view('login');
}
public function logout()
{
    $this->Test->updation1();
    $this->session->unset_userdata('usr_sess');
    $this->session->sess_destroy();

}   
public function xyz(){ 
    if($this->input->post('submit')){
        $uid = $this->input->post('eid');
        $pass = $this->input->post('pass');
        $login_id = $this->Test->login($uid,$pass);
        $sess_ary = array('lgid' => $login_id['id'] );
        $this->session->set_userdata('usr_sess',$sess_ary);
        if($login_id)
         {   if($login_id['toggle']==0) 
              {   

                  $this->Test->updation();
                  return $this->load->view('logout');
               }
              else{
                $this->logout();
                $this->session->set_flashdata('already_existing','This account is already logged 
                                                                                               in');
                return $this->load->view('login');      
              }

         }
        else
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('Login_failed','Invalid Username/Password');
            return $this->load->view('login');
        }
    }
    else if($this->input->post('logout'))
    {   if($this->session->has_userdata['usr_sess']['lgid']){
           $this->logout();
           $this->session->set_flashdata('Logged_out','Logged out successfully');
           return $this->load->view('login');}
        else{
            return $this->load->view('login');
        }   
    }
}
```

Before removing index.php from URL, code was working fine, but now only the first view(login page) is loaded and after clicking the submit button, it is redirecting to the same view, i.e. login page.
Please help me

Comment: "index/Home/xyz" - Should "index" be in the URL?

Comment: No, it should not be there. Actually, I once tried it, because I thought it might work. But it didn't.